# Error to convert date in TALEND open studio

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I'm trying to convert this kind of date "31/01/2014" to this format "31-01-2014", I tried to use TalendDate.parseDate("dd/MM/yyyy",row.date)... but does't work.

This is the error:

At least job "payment" has a compile errors, please fix and export again. Error Line: 1709 Detail Message: The method parseDate(String, String) in the type TalendDate is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date) There may be some other errors caused by JVM compatibility. Make sure your JVM setup is similar to the studio.

Can sameone help me?

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

TalendDate.parseDate(String, String) method accepts both parameters as String. You are passing 2nd parameter as Date, that is the problem.

Comment: How can I convert string to Date in Talend?

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind going through the below URL for these data type conversions. You could implement one of those in your requirement.

http://talendhowto.com/2017/08/29/convert-between-different-datatypes/